# Install multiple apps in one step (Android)

Tags: android, batch-file, apk

I'm trying to find a way to "package" my apps in one super app that downloads and installs all my apps.

So far my options seem to be:

- Make an interface app that links to each of my apps in the app store (too many steps).
- Create a big apk file containing all my apps that would drop my apps in a folder on the device and run a script to install them all (not sure if possible).
- ?

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> create a big apk file containing all my apps that would drop my apps in a folder on the device and run a script to install them all (not sure if possible)

You cannot install them. You can help the user install them, by calling `startActivity()` to bring up each one in sequence, but this will be a similar number of steps to the approach that you rejected. It also means that you will take up double the disk space (copy in your "super" APK plus the installed copy of each app).

> ???

Have only one app in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Good points. The startactivity() thing is interesting. Steps are similar but there should be little load times inbetween. For the ??? part, I'm wondering if there are creative solutions I'm not thinking about.

Comment: @Tominlux: "I'm wondering if there are creative solutions I'm not thinking about" -- both answers to your question have suggested that you not have multiple apps in the first place. Who, besides yourself, cares that there are multiple apps instead of just one app?

Answer (score 0):

For systems that have ROOT permission,copy apks to /data/app directory.For the other,achieve every function in one package and show these functions' activities in launcher.Just like several apks have been inatalled in one time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I'd like to do that all devices, rooted and unrooted

Comment: Installing app without users' permission should not be allowed from the point of both security and privacy.So maybe there is no sollution in such case except making all functions in one package.